# Variable used within its own initial value (Swift and Xcode 9 beta)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm getting the following error in this code:
Variable used within its own initial value (Swift and Xcode 9 beta)

I'm getting this error thrown on line 82 by the following piece of code:
**let values = ["username": username, "email": email, "pic":""]**

Could someone please help me in figuring out why I'm getting this error?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

    func signup(){
        guard let username = username.text else{
            print("username issue")
            return
        guard let email = email.text else{
            print("e-mail issue")
            return
        }
        guard let password = password.text else{
            print("password issue")
            return
        }
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!)
                return

            }
            guard let uid = user?.uid else {
                return
            }

            let userReference = self.databaseRef.child("users").child(uid)
            let values = ["username": username, "email": email, "pic":""]

            userReference.updateChildValues(values
                , withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                    if error != nil{
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completetion: nil)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have 2 functions with same name. Each function should have a different name within the scope of a class.    `@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {`
       ` loginUser()`
   `}`

    `@IBAction func signup(_ sender: Any) {`
        `signupUser()`
    `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your missing a closing "}" in the first guard statement in your signup function.

Comment: thanks! that fixed it..I have another error now..but I suppose I should ask another question if I can't figure it out

Comment: No problem. You got it.